# Why is the \raisebox necessary here in order to align the equation proberly?

Tags: tables, equations, tabularx, adjustbox, xltabular

I have just stumbled across the following problem:

I would like to align the matrices in the last column so that it starts with the other columns.

However, I need an offset for this, which I implement with the \raisebox command. But I'm wondering why this is necessary. Is there a better solution?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

{
\centering    
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.4em} >{\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.7\textwidth} }
    5 & Mit dem Operationsverstärker wird ähnlich verfahren: hier wird der Ausgangsstrom I\_VCVS dem Gleichungssystem hinzugefügt. Alle Elemente der Netzliste sind damit abgearbeitet. & \raisebox{-.85\height}{$\left[\begin{matrix}
        \dfrac{1}{R1} & -\dfrac{1}{R1} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        -\dfrac{1}{R1} & \dfrac{1}{R1}+\dfrac{1}{R2} & -\dfrac{1}{R2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & -\dfrac{1}{R2} & \dfrac{1}{R2} & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & v & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}\right]\cdot\left[\begin{array}{@{} c @{}}
        V1 \\
        V2 \\
        V3 \\
        0 \\
        I\_V0 \\
        I\_VCVS \\
    \end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{@{} c @{}}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        U0 \\
        0 \\
    \end{array}\right]$} \\
    6 & Zum Abschluss werden die zum Masse-Potential gehörende Zeile und Spalte wegen ihrer linearen Abhängigkeit entfernt. Das Ergebnis ist gesuchte \textbf{MNA}-Gleichungssystem. Auf diese Weise stellt im Übrigen auch \textbf{SPICE} seine Netzwerkgleichungen auf & \raisebox{-.85\height}{$\left[\begin{matrix}
        \dfrac{1}{R1} & -\dfrac{1}{R1} & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        -\dfrac{1}{R1} & \dfrac{1}{R1}+\dfrac{1}{R2} & -\dfrac{1}{R2} & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & -\dfrac{1}{R2} & \dfrac{1}{R2} & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & v & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}\right]\cdot\left[\begin{array}{@{} c @{}}
        V1 \\
        V2 \\
        V3 \\
        I\_V0 \\
        I\_VCVS \\
    \end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{@{} c @{}}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        U0 \\
        0 \\
    \end{array}\right]$} \\
\end{xltabular}
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really think that presenting long text in a narrow column is good for the readers? Why not the matrices just below the text using the normal width?

Comment: The overall page size is smaller than shown in this MRE. Therefore, the sizes are just right to display the content pleasantly.

Comment: You mean wider, not smaller, I guess. Anyway, you're wasting space, in my opinion, for no better outlook. Instead of `\raisebox` you could use `adjustbox` with option `valign=T`.

Comment: @egreg This seems to be the solution I was looking for! Thank you.
FYI: I really meant smaller, but the text size is also smaller, and the font has been changed to Times New Roman (i have to use a given .cls-File).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `adjustbox` with the option `valign=t`, so you don't have to guess.

I made several other fixes: for instance `bmatrix` instead of so many `\left[` and `\right]`; also `\tfrac` instead of `\dfrac`, that helps in keeping the matrices to a readable size without too much space between rows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times font

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amssymb} % not with newtx

\begin{document}

\begingroup\small
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{
  @{}
  c
  X
  >{\centering\arraybackslash\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}}p{.7\textwidth}
  @{}
}
5 & Mit dem Operationsverstärker wird ähnlich verfahren: hier wird der
    Ausgangsstrom I\_VCVS dem Gleichungssystem hinzugefügt. Alle Elemente 
    der Netzliste sind damit abgearbeitet. &
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}$
      \begin{bmatrix}
        \tfrac{1}{R1} & -\tfrac{1}{R1} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        -\tfrac{1}{R1} & \tfrac{1}{R1}+\tfrac{1}{R2} & -\tfrac{1}{R2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & -\tfrac{1}{R2} & \tfrac{1}{R2} & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & v & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
      \end{bmatrix}
      \cdot
      \begin{bmatrix}
        V1 \\
        V2 \\
        V3 \\
        0 \\
        I\_V0 \\
        I\_VCVS \\
      \end{bmatrix}
      =
      \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        U0 \\
        0 \\
      \end{bmatrix}
      $\end{adjustbox} \\
6 & Zum Abschluss werden die zum Masse-Potential gehörende Zeile und Spalte
    wegen ihrer linearen Abhängigkeit entfernt. Das Ergebnis ist gesuchte
    \textbf{MNA}-Gleichungssystem. Auf diese Weise stellt im Übrigen auch
    \textbf{SPICE} seine Netzwerkgleichungen auf &
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}$
    \begin{bmatrix}
      \tfrac{1}{R1} & -\tfrac{1}{R1} & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
      -\tfrac{1}{R1} & \tfrac{1}{R1}+\tfrac{1}{R2} & -\tfrac{1}{R2} & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & -\tfrac{1}{R2} & \tfrac{1}{R2} & 0 & 1 \\
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & v & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \cdot
    \begin{bmatrix}
      V1 \\
      V2 \\
      V3 \\
      I\_V0 \\
      I\_VCVS \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
      0 \\
      0 \\
      0 \\
      U0 \\
      0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    $\end{adjustbox} \\
\end{xltabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I don't think this is a good way to present your ideas: reading a narrow column is difficult.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times font
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amssymb} % not with newtx

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{4}% just to get 5 and 6 as in your example

\item Mit dem Operationsverstärker wird ähnlich verfahren: hier wird der
      Ausgangsstrom I\_VCVS dem Gleichungssystem hinzugefügt. Alle Elemente 
      der Netzliste sind damit abgearbeitet.
      \[
      \begin{bmatrix}
        \tfrac{1}{R1} & -\tfrac{1}{R1} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        -\tfrac{1}{R1} & \tfrac{1}{R1}+\tfrac{1}{R2} & -\tfrac{1}{R2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & -\tfrac{1}{R2} & \tfrac{1}{R2} & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & v & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
      \end{bmatrix}
      \cdot
      \begin{bmatrix}
        V1 \\
        V2 \\
        V3 \\
        0 \\
        I\_V0 \\
        I\_VCVS \\
      \end{bmatrix}
      =
      \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        U0 \\
        0 \\
      \end{bmatrix}
      \]
\item Zum Abschluss werden die zum Masse-Potential gehörende Zeile und Spalte
      wegen ihrer linearen Abhängigkeit entfernt. Das Ergebnis ist gesuchte
      \textbf{MNA}-Gleichungssystem. Auf diese Weise stellt im Übrigen auch
      \textbf{SPICE} seine Netzwerkgleichungen auf
      \[
      \begin{bmatrix}
        \tfrac{1}{R1} & -\tfrac{1}{R1} & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        -\tfrac{1}{R1} & \tfrac{1}{R1}+\tfrac{1}{R2} & -\tfrac{1}{R2} & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & -\tfrac{1}{R2} & \tfrac{1}{R2} & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & v & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
      \end{bmatrix}
      \cdot
      \begin{bmatrix}
        V1 \\
        V2 \\
        V3 \\
        I\_V0 \\
        I\_VCVS \\
      \end{bmatrix}
      =
      \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        U0 \\
        0 \\
      \end{bmatrix}
      \]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Narrow columns *are* hard to read, but you've made things worse by justifying that text.  Please use ragged right,

Comment: @barbarabeeton I agree, but wanted to follow the OP's idea, mainly in order to show its weaknesses.

Answer (score 1):

Even with some determined de-crufting and streamlining of your code, it's not easy to actually make the `xltabular` environment fit into the width of the textblock.

[image]

> Is there a better solution?

Your readers will almost certainly appreciate it if you decide to make the layout a lot less crowded, e.g., by switching to an enumerated-list setup.

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % '2.0' is much too profligate

% new:
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\Centering' and '\RaggedRight' macros
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

%% Layout #1: 'xltabular'
\begingroup
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt} % default: 5pt
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt
\noindent  
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} 
   l 
   >{\RaggedRight}X 
   >{\Centering}p{0.7\textwidth} 
   @{}}
5 & 
Mit dem Operationsverstärker wird ähnlich verfahren: hier wird der Ausgangsstrom I\_VCVS dem Gleichungssystem hinzugefügt. Alle Elemente der Netzliste sind damit abgearbeitet. & 
\raisebox{-.85\height}{%
$\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{R1} & -\frac{1}{R1} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    -\frac{1}{R1} & \frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2} & -\frac{1}{R2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -\frac{1}{R2} & \frac{1}{R2} & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & -1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & -1 &  0 & 0 \\
    0 & v & 1 &  0 &  0 & 0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}%\cdot
 \begin{bmatrix}
    V1 \\
    V2 \\
    V3 \\
    0 \\
    I\_V0 \\
    I\_VCVS \\
 \end{bmatrix}=
 \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    U0 \\
    0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$} 
\\
6 & 
Zum Abschluss werden die zum Masse-Potential gehörende Zeile und Spalte wegen ihrer linearen Abhängigkeit entfernt. Das Ergebnis ist gesuchte \textbf{MNA}-Gleichungssystem. Auf diese Weise stellt im Übrigen auch \textbf{SPICE} seine Netzwerkgleichungen auf & 
\raisebox{-.85\height}{%
$\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{R1} & -\frac{1}{R1} & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    -\frac{1}{R1} & \frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2} & -\frac{1}{R2} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -\frac{1}{R2} & \frac{1}{R2} & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & v & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}%\cdot
 \begin{bmatrix}
    V1 \\
    V2 \\
    V3 \\
    I\_V0 \\
    I\_VCVS \\
 \end{bmatrix}=
 \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    U0 \\
    0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$}
\end{xltabular}

\endgroup

\clearpage

%% Layout #2: use an enumerated list
\begin{enumerate}[start=5,left=0pt,label=\arabic*]
\item Mit dem Operationsverstärker wird ähnlich verfahren: hier wird der Ausgangsstrom I\_VCVS dem Gleichungssystem hinzugefügt. Alle Elemente der Netzliste sind damit abgearbeitet.
\[
 \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{R1} & -\frac{1}{R1} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    -\frac{1}{R1} & \frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2} & -\frac{1}{R2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -\frac{1}{R2} & \frac{1}{R2} & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & -1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & -1 &  0 & 0 \\
    0 & v & 1 &  0 &  0 & 0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}%\cdot
 \begin{bmatrix}
    V1 \\
    V2 \\
    V3 \\
    0 \\
    I\_V0 \\
    I\_VCVS \\
 \end{bmatrix}=
 \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    U0 \\
    0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}
\]
\item Zum Abschluss werden die zum Masse-Potential gehörende Zeile und Spalte wegen ihrer linearen Abhängigkeit entfernt. Das Ergebnis ist gesuchte \textbf{MNA}-Gleichungssystem. Auf diese Weise stellt im Übrigen auch \textbf{SPICE} seine Netzwerkgleichungen auf.
\[
 \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{R1} & -\frac{1}{R1} & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    -\frac{1}{R1} & \frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2} & -\frac{1}{R2} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -\frac{1}{R2} & \frac{1}{R2} & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & v & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}%\cdot
 \begin{bmatrix}
    V1 \\
    V2 \\
    V3 \\
    I\_V0 \\
    I\_VCVS \\
 \end{bmatrix}=
 \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    U0 \\
    0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I know that the content isn't looking great in the MRE provided. I appreciate your suggestion and I will take it into consideration, but as pointed out in my other comment, the final page size differs from the given one. 

Back to the initial question: Why do I even need the \raisebox command?

Comment: @FixFox - The `X` column type is nothing but a `p` column type in disguise. Now, material in adjacent `p`-type columns is "top-aligned" -- but what exactly does this mean? For a `p`-type cell whose contents consist of ordinary text only, the top-alignment anchor is the baseline of the first line of text in the cell. In contrast, if the `p`-type cell consists of inline-mode math only, the anchoring baseline is taken to the line that contains the `=` symbol (or some natural analogue). One way to break this association of the baselines is to encase the right-hand cell in a `\raisebox` wrapper.

Comment: @FixFox (continued from previous comment). Another way to break this association is to run `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}`; here, `m` is a variant of `p` that performs alignment on the vertical center rather than on the "first line". A downside of this method is that the numbers "5" and "6" in the left-hand column will also be centered vertically -- this is almost surely not desired. Deep down, it all boils down to some design shortcomings of the underlying `\halign` TeX primitive. If you crave an alternative, look into the `tabularray` package, which doesn't employ `\halign`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this enlightening explanation and the additional tips. This makes sense.